# How to use Github Pages with Dependencies?

Tags: git, github, npm, bower, github-pages

Sorry if this is more of a general question.

I set up a github pages account under: **username.github.io**

This allows me to access my applications on: **username.github.io/repository-name**

Now I am wondering, how do you guys handle the dependency problem, since your application probably requires `node_modules`, `bower_components` or other dependencies?

In my understanding you don't want to have dependencies in your repository, because repositories become unnecessarily bloated. We invented `.gitignore` for that.

But your SPAs won't work without them.

Do you just create a `gh-pages` branch **with all dependencies** and push it with dependencies?

How do you handle switching branches on your local machine then, since switching branches from `master` to `gh-pages` and back to `master` will result in your dependencies missing in `master` and require you to `npm install` and `bower install` every single time?

Comment: Github pages will either a) serve your *static* content or b) compile your Github compatible Jekyll site into static content, then serve it. If you're just using npm / Bower to create these front-end resources (JS, CSS, etc.), then you can compile them and include it in your repo.  If you're wanting a running Node instance though, you'll have to run it on your own server.

Comment: So you are telling me, to just include all my dependencies in my repo?

Comment: I wouldn't include the dependencies in your entire repo, I'd just have them inside the `gh-pages` branch.  And it will only work if there isn't any server-side processing, everything will have to be handled through HTML and JavaScript.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can consider your `gh-pages` branch more as a server than as a git branch - so many of the common rules for git branches don't apply there.

It's not uncommon, if you are developing an application hosted on GH:Pages, that your `gh-pages` branch is full of auto-generated content - exactly the opposite of what you'd do on a *normal* git branch, in which you **don't** version generated resources.

So it wouldn't be uncommon to have some build process that generates the contents of the `gh-pages` branch. You can learn a bit about [how Learn Git Branching does the trick](https://github.com/pcottle/learnGitBranching/blob/7adbd2967aa6d32a7f3f96804e75e5c895b9ccfd/README.md#building-yourself--contributing-functionality), for example, or read the [Jekyll on GitHub Pages docs](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/github-pages/) to get a better insight.